# hrtimer runs even thogh it is not started

Tags: linux, time, kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm performing

```
hrtimer_init(hr_timer, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
```

And after a while ( 30, maybe 60 seconds ), i perform:

```
hrtimer_start(hr_timer, ktime_set(0, timeout), HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
```

And immediatelly after, in less than 1 second, i perform

```
ktime_to_timeval(hrtimer_expires_remaining(hr_timer));
```

The output timeval struct contains the time since hrtimer_init, and not from the start.
What is akward, is that this doesn't happens each time, and it happens only to one of my many timers ( only to the first that i initialize ).

Any thoughts ?

Comment: It seems that even if i call, or i don't, hrtimer_cancel on the timer before start, the first time for hrtimer_start returns 1 which means: already active, so my timeout and the whole hrtimer_start is just ignored.

Comment: What is your kernel version ? And can you post a minimal example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a stupid hardcoded variable caused a reset on timerID 0.
I've even created a separate module with the timers alone to see if the hrtimer wrapper is working properly.